# rquestion about how variables works on ruby

Tags: html, ruby

I am new to Ruby and I am a bit confused. please see example below:
part1 got modified after the code on #2 is run. I thought string2 stored the variable only, and part1 shouldn't be changed, but when I print them using html code, the outputs for part1 and string2 are the same. I also tried to put  "part1_copy = part1" before #2 and put part1_copy to HTML to print. However, it's still not working correctly. so how can I print the actual part1 out?

```
#########ruby code##################
#1
part1 = string[0,50]
part2 = string[51,99]

#2
string2 = part1.insert(30,part2 )


###########HTML code##############
puts <<HTML 
……………

<h3> #1  </h3>
<pre>#{part1}</pre>

<h3> #2</h3>
<pre>#{string2}</pre>

 ……………
 HTML
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `insert` is destructive in Ruby meaning, whenever you use it, it will change the content of the variable you used it on. In you example, you have an equation `string2 = part1.insert(30, part2)` thus, your `part1` variable was updated.